# (Rubymotion) How can I do this custom view in Formotion?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion, formotion

I am struggling at the moment to make a custom Form with Formotion(Also I'm very new in Rubymotion). Maybe I have to try another framework or maybe not doing any framework at all....

I try to make this:

[image]

At this moment I created this in Formotion:

[image]

The problem is the Border between password and email. It has to start under the text field and not under the icon. It is a small change but I don't know how to do this with Formotion. Are those kind of things easy possible? Thanks in advanced!

Here is my code:

```
class LoginScreen < PM::FormotionScreen

  title ""

  def table_data
    {
      sections: [
        {
          title: "Login",
          rows: [
            {
              title:  "Email",
              key:    :email,
              type:   :email,
              placeholder: "me@mail.com",
              auto_correction: :no,
              auto_capitalization: :none,
              text_alignment: UITextAlignmentLeft
            }, {
              title: "Password",
              key: :password,
              type: :password,
              placeholder: "required",
              secure: true,
              text_alignment: UITextAlignmentLeft
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  end
end
```

I overwritten the EmailRow to insert the icon

```
motion_require 'string_row'

module Formotion
  module RowType
    class EmailRow < StringRow

      def build_cell(cell)
        cell.selectionStyle = self.row.selection_style || UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue
        field = UITextField.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRectZero)
        field.tag = TEXT_FIELD_TAG

        observe(self.row, "value") do |old_value, new_value|
          break_with_semaphore do
            update_text_field(new_value)
          end
        end

        field.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing
        field.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter
        field.textAlignment = row.text_alignment || UITextAlignmentRight

        field.keyboardType = keyboardType

        field.secureTextEntry = true if row.secure?
        field.returnKeyType = row.return_key || UIReturnKeyNext
        field.autocapitalizationType = row.auto_capitalization if row.auto_capitalization
        field.autocorrectionType = row.auto_correction if row.auto_correction
        field.clearButtonMode = row.clear_button || UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing
        field.enabled = row.editable?
        field.inputAccessoryView = input_accessory_view(row.input_accessory) if row.input_accessory

        add_callbacks(field)

        cell.swizzle(:layoutSubviews) do
          def layoutSubviews
            old_layoutSubviews

            # viewWithTag is terrible, but I think it's ok to use here...
            formotion_field = self.viewWithTag(TEXT_FIELD_TAG)
            formotion_field.sizeToFit

            field_frame = formotion_field.frame
            field_frame.origin.x = self.textLabel.frame.origin.x + Formotion::RowType::Base.field_buffer * 2
            field_frame.origin.y = ((self.frame.size.height - field_frame.size.height) / 2.0).round
            field_frame.size.width = self.frame.size.width - field_frame.origin.x - Formotion::RowType::Base.field_buffer
            formotion_field.frame = field_frame

          end
        end

        if UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion >= "6.0"
          field.swizzle(:setText) do
            def setText(text)
              r = old_setText(text)
              self.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEventEditingChanged)
              r
            end
          end
        end

        field.font = BW::Font.new(row.font) if row.font
        field.placeholder = row.placeholder
        field.text = row_value

        icon = UIImage.imageNamed("icons/mail.png")
        icon_view = UIImageView.alloc.initWithImage(icon)
        icon_view.setFrame(CGRectMake(20, 18, icon_view.frame.size.width, icon_view.frame.size.height))

        cell.addSubview(icon_view)
        cell.addSubview(field)
        cell.textLabel.hidden = true
        field

      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was extremely easy in the end. Just add an image in `cell.imageView` in EmailRow.

added this line:

```
cell.imageView.image = UIImage.imageNamed("icons/mail.png")
cell.imageView.setFrame(CGRectMake(20, 18, cell.imageView.frame.size.width,       cell.imageView.frame.size.height))
```

and you access the cell with the code below, for example:

```
cell = @form.table.visibleCell.first
```

Comment: I have the same question, how did you get the cell object from Formotion::Form object?

Comment: @user310525 you can access the cell by accessing `@form.table.visibleCells.last`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend disabling the built-in border entirely and adding a pseudo-border using a thin `UIView`. That way you can set the `frame` to position it in the right position and give it a backgroundColor of `#E3E3E5k` like in your mockup.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I was trying to disable the border but without any success as well. Do you know by any change how to delete the border? Im thinking the border is being set outside the row for some reason...

Comment: Tried to add a create a little UIView and put them, but somewhere in the code of formotion, (or somewhere else) it puts the border on top of the cell.

Comment: Try `self.view.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor` in your `viewWillAppear` (make sure to call super).

Comment: Thanks! That almost did the trick. Now all the separators are gone. (Also the outlines). Will try to hack around. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: You bet Michael. Good luck with the project!

Comment: In the end i just added an image in cell.imageView. As it is standard in ios, isn't it a nice option to add to formotion? Have some spare some next week to make a pull request.